Forcing and chain conditions
I have been trying to understand an argument from a paper from Baumgartner. I have the feeling that is a basic argument because he uses it in many times throughout the proof
I can't see why the existence of such D is followed by the chain condition. I have tried to generalize this argument to names of subsets of ordinals but I don't know where the chain condition enters in the proof.

Which paper and the proposition are you reading in Baumgartner's paper?

I'm reading Iterated forcing from Baumgartner and is the lemma 6.3

My guess is that the following standard fact is relevant: If $\mathbb{P}$ is a forcing with $\kappa$-c.c. and for a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter $G$, if $f\in V[G]$, $f\colon A\to B$ for $A,B\in V$, then there is $F\in V$, $F\colon A\to [B]^{<\kappa}$ such that $f(x)\in F(x)$ for every $x\in A$.

YES! How could I forgot about that, thank you so much!

I think it's easiest to see this by shifting from $q$ to the function $h$ which enumerates $dom(q)$ in order (or rather, the corresponding name $\dot{h}$). Think about the possible values that could be forced for $\dot{h}(i)$ for a given $i<\kappa$. By the $\kappa$-chain condition there are $<\kappa$-many such values (since any two distinct values of $h(i)$ must come from incompatible conditions). Since the possible elements of $dom(q)$ are exactly the possible values of $h(i)$ for $i<\kappa$, we get $(<\kappa)\times(<\kappa)$-many possible elements of $dom(q)$.
